# Different size columns in a gridview xamarin C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

How can I resize the columns of a gridview popualted from a list.

Below is my code:

```
             List<string> comanda = new List<string>();
             GridView gv;

             var gridview = FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.gridView1);

             //first row
             comanda.Add("teeest");
             comanda.Add("1");
             comanda.Add("222");
             comanda.Add("1");
             comanda.Add("1");
             //second row
             comanda.Add("teeeeeeeeeest");
             comanda.Add("1");
             comanda.Add("222");
             comanda.Add("1");
             comanda.Add("1");
            adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSelectableListItem, comanda);

            gridview.Adapter = adapter2;
```

axml like that:

```
           <GridView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="382.5dp"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="5"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        />
```

See the result, and what I expect in this image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFWjd.jpg

Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: I have another question. I'll try to make first column bigger than other, so I use diffrent GridView.LayoutParams, but the first column overlaps with the second. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: You can create a new thread so that I can provide more details .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you set the **Adapter** of GridView as the default style which define by system.

So you need a custom Adapter .

Create a new class called TextAdapter that subclasses **BaseAdapter**:

```
public class TextAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
  Context context;

  List<string> Sources;

  public TextAdapter(Context c , List<string> s)
  {
    context = c;
    Sources = s;
  }

  public override int Count
  {
     get { return Sources.Count; }
  }

  public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
  {
     return null;
  }

  public override long GetItemId(int position)
  {
     return 0;
  }

  // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
  public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
     TextView textView;

     if (convertView == null)
     {
       textView =new TextView(context);
       textView.SetLines(1);
     }
     else
     {
        textView = (TextView)convertView;
     }

     textView.SetText(Sources[position],null);

     return textView;
  }

}
```

And set the **Adapter** in Activity

```
gridview.Adapter = new TextAdapter(this,comanda);
```